# Stress testing of flow (Rest) with JMeter

Tags: rest, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, stress-testing

I have a rest service which receives a customer's ID and an input, acording to this the services response something different, it's basically a menu, but the reponse could be different (depends on the customers input), so I need to stress this service to see how many request the server can handle and try to determine the max TPS, but since is a flow I don't know how I can simulate this, any idea or page that can be useful?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

What you mostly need is an understanding of how to handle dynamic parameters. Imagine you are simulating a user which goes on a blog, views a random blog article and then posts a comment about it.

It's all about designing a user which has a dynamic behavior, which changes depending on variables or server output. [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) supports this kind of simulation very well by providing dozen of useful components like:

- [CSV Datasets](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config),
- [Regexp Variable extractors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor),
- and more.

We have written an article which explains how to [simulate users with a dynamic behavior](https://octoperf.com/blog/2015/07/28/load-testing-rest-api/). It's very similar to what you would do in JMeter since OctoPerf is based on JMeter, with a Web UI built on top.